# Using Resilience4j TimeLimiter on service methods

Tags: java, spring-boot, resilience4j

Previously my project had Hystrix for timeouts. Since after Spring Boot upgrade it turned out that Hystrix is no longer supported/developed I needed alternative. One alternative seems to be Resilience4j but I get `io.github.resilience4j.timelimiter.configure.IllegalReturnTypeException` with it.

Example from Hystrix:

```
  @HystrixCommand(commandProperties = {@HystrixProperty(name = TIMEOUT, value = "60000")})
  public List<CustomBlahClass> getBlaBlaBla(...) {
```

If I now replace `@HystrixCommand(...)` with `@TimeLimiter(name = "myTimeLimiter")`

I get error:

> io.github.resilience4j.timelimiter.configure.IllegalReturnTypeException:
> package.CustomBlahClass
> package.MyService#getBlaBlaBla has
> unsupported by @TimeLimiter return type. CompletionStage expected.

When I searched this issue I found that methods need to be of type `CompletableFuture<T>`.

Is refactoring all methods in all services to return CompletableFuture really the only option or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have an update on this? I'm having the same issue.